# Javascript members not updated after function call

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying create a simple three.js app, but I'm getting stuck on some of the nuances of javascript. I don't really know how to explain the problem without an example:

```
var Model = function() {
    THREE.Object3D.call(this);
    this.loadedMesh = null;
    this.meshIsLoaded = false;
};

Model.prototype = {
    constructor: Model,

    load: function(path, mtlName, objName) {
        var onProgress = function(xhr) {...};

        var onError = function(err) {...};

        THREE.Loader.Handlers.add( /\.dds$/i, new THREE.DDSLoader());
        mtlLoader.setPath(path);
        mtlLoader.load(mtlName, function(materials) {
            materials.preload();
            objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
            objLoader.setPath(path);
            objLoader.load(objName, function(object) {
                object.position.set(0, -5, 10);
                object.scale.set(5, 5, 5);
                object.rotation.y = Math.PI; // 180 degrees
                scene.add(object);
                this.loadedMesh = object;
                this.meshIsLoaded = true;
            });
        }, onProgress, onError);
    }
};
```

This wrapper should be a container for a three model. The loading works fine, but when I try and save the Model into a variable, none of the internal members are altered outside of the Model scope.

```
var spaceman = new Model();
spaceman.load("ACES/", "acesjustforroomshow.mtl", "acesjustforroomshow.obj");
...
function update() {
    if (spaceman.meshIsLoaded)
        spaceman.loadedMesh.rotation.x += 0.1;
}
```

It's weird because if I debug the app and wait until the model is loaded, I can hover over the internal members and they are populated. When I hover over the spaceman object, the values for loadedMesh and meshIsLoaded remain the default.

Is there some aspect of prototyping that I'm not understanding here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the issue is the `this` variable. Within the callback function you're passing to `objLoader.load`, it may no longer be set to your object. If I'm right, either of the below fixes should work:

Using `bind`:

```
objLoader.load(objName, function(object) {
    object.position.set(0, -5, 10);
    object.scale.set(5, 5, 5);
    object.rotation.y = Math.PI; // 180 degrees
    scene.add(object);
    this.loadedMesh = object;
    this.meshIsLoaded = true;
}.bind(this));
```

Capturing `this` in another variable:

```
var that = this;
objLoader.load(objName, function(object) {
    object.position.set(0, -5, 10);
    object.scale.set(5, 5, 5);
    object.rotation.y = Math.PI; // 180 degrees
    scene.add(object);
    that.loadedMesh = object;
    that.meshIsLoaded = true;
});
```

Comment: Awesome! That was exactly the problem. I went with the temp 'that' variable approach.